# PHP filter array function

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array, filter, filtering

I need a filter as function. I already have:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array('name' => 'John Doe', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com'),
    array('name' => 'Marry Lies', 'email' => 'marry@gmail.com'),
    array('name' => 'Andrew Joe', 'email' => 'andrew@gmail.com'),
);

$like = 'jo';
$kol = 'name';
$result = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($kol,$like) {
    if (stripos($item[$kol], $like) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
print_r($result);
```

I need it as a function like:

```
function filter($array,$like,$kol)
```

How can I make above code work in a function. Please write the whole code here.

Comment: Above code returns row [0] and [2]. How can I make it return rows in a sequence so it will return [0] and [1]?

Comment: `array_values() ` will resequence the array for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. The issue is that when using `array_filter` (as mentioned in the small print on [the manual page](https://www.php.net/array_filter)), *array keys are preserved*. To re-index the result, you can run it through `array_values`, which will reset the keys to start from zero.

As a function, this could look like this:

```
function filter($array, $like, $kol) {
    $filtered = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($kol, $like) {
        return stripos($item[$kol], $like) !== false;
    });
    
    return array_values($filtered);
}
```

Full demo here: https://3v4l.org/slCeX